# Is it possible to let Gerrit randomly pick a reviewer?

Tags: git, gerrit

Is it possible to let Gerrit randomly pick a reviewer?

If it isn't possible by configure Gerrit, is it possible by doing it via Git commands / scripts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't configure gerrit to assign a random reviewer, nor a default reviewer/per project. See issue [upstream](http://code.google.com/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=681).

You can however use the query API to get all open review requests, then you can iterate over the JSON data and find the ones with no active reviewer from a certain group

```
ssh gerrit.server gerrit query --format=JSON status:open NOT reviewerin:<your group>
```

You can then add the reviewer using the set-reviewers API:

```
ssh gerrit.server gerrit set-reviewers --add <name> <ChangeId Received From Above>
```